# Solving a linear Diophantine equation where c is a multiple of $7$ (or any other prime)

Tags: diophantine-equations

I want to solve $ax + by = 7k$ (a multiple of 7) with all letters being integers.

For example: $6x + y = 7k$. With Wolfram Alpha I found one parameterization of the solution space:

$y = 7n - 6x$ ($n \in \mathbb{Z}$).

But somehow I found another parameterization, which I am convinced is also correct:

$x = 7n + y$

I am interested in both forms. How can I derive these two forms myself, if I change $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Thank you Thomas, but I look for $y = f(x)$ and $x = g(y)$. Like in the example: $x=7n +y$

Comment: $7n+y=7(n+y)-6y.$ The two two parameterizarions give the same $x,y$ pairs.

Comment: Basically, the function $(n,y)\to(n+y,y)$ has inverse $(m,y)\to(m-y,y).$

Comment: You’ve also got a paramterization $x=7n+8y.$

Comment: I have the condition that 6x + y is a multiple of 7 and from that I want to demonstrate that 5x + 8y is a multiple of 13 (given some further constraints like x and y are both between 0 and 7). To check all cases I would like to have one of the two forms  y=f(x) or x=g(y). If I use the most convenient form, the proof is quite short, otherwise it gets ugly.

Comment: I am working on a proof for the OEIS sequence A348480

Comment: Given that there is literally no information in OEIS A348480, it is unclear why you would reference it.

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is a prime, and given $a,b$ with $a$ is not divisible by $p,$ then there is some $a’$ such that $aa’-1=pm.$ Then your equation is equivalent $aa’x+ba’y=pka’$ or $x+ba’y=p(k-mx )$ so you get a parameterization: $$x=pk-(ba’)y$$

Note $a’$ and $m$ are determined by $a,$ so these answers are parameterized by $y.$

---

So for $(a,b,p)=(5,8,13),$ $a’=8,m=3.$ Then you get:

$$x=13k-64y$$

You can reduce $ba’$ modulo $p,$ which in this case reduces:

$$x=13k+y$$

---

If $a$ is divisible by $p$ and $b$ is not, $(x,y)$ is parameterized by $(n,pm).$ $y$ cannot take just any value in this case.

If $a,b$ are both divisible by $p,$ then the solutions are parameterized by $x=n-y.$

---

This is all best expressed modulo $p:$

$$ax\equiv (-b)y\pmod p$$ If $a$ is not divisible by $p,$ $a$ has a multiplicative  inverse, modulo $p,$ and this came be expressed:

$$x\equiv (-a’b)y\pmod p$$ or $x=pn-a’by$ for some $n.$

Comment: That's the perfect answer. Exactly what I needed. If you are interested I can send you the proof that any number b consisting of 13 ones and less than 65 zeros that fulfills the constraint 13 | b and 13 | rev(b) is always divisible by 7 and also rev(b) is divisible by 7. (rev("123") = "321"). For this proof (still in the making) I have many Diophantine equations.